# How to prevent installation variables to be placed in the response file in 6.x?

Tags: install4j

How can I prevent some installation variables from being placed into the response file? The reason is: during an update I want some particular variables to always have their default values and not be overwritten. In particular for some custom form components like a checkbox or radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
context.unregisterResponseFileVariable("variableName")
```

before the response file is written.